# After Updating Android Studio 3.1 Get Error while Release Signed APK

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.1

After migrating my existing project to Android Studio 3.1, it is not compiling. Below are the log details:

> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ResourceException: Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>       at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doFullTaskAction(MergeResources.java:296)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor352.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
>       ... 32 more
>   Caused by: Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>       at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergedResourceWriter.end(MergedResourceWriter.java:332)
>       at com.android.ide.common.res2.DataMerger.mergeData(DataMerger.java:301)
>       at com.android.ide.common.res2.ResourceMerger.mergeData(ResourceMerger.java:412)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doFullTaskAction(MergeResources.java:285)
>       ... 47 more
>       Suppressed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Some file processing failed, see logs for details
>           at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.QueuedResourceProcessor.waitForAll(QueuedResourceProcessor.java:121)
>           at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.QueuedResourceProcessor.end(QueuedResourceProcessor.java:141)
>           at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.QueueableAapt2.close(QueueableAapt2.java:104)
>           at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doFullTaskAction(MergeResources.java:293)
>           ... 47 more
>   Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
>       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:462)
>       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
>       at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergedResourceWriter.end(MergedResourceWriter.java:327)
>       ... 50 more
>   Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
>       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:462)
>       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
>       at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.QueueableAapt2.lambda$compile$0(QueueableAapt2.java:136)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       ... 1 more
>   Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>       at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.handleOutput(AaptProcess.java:443)
>       at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.err(AaptProcess.java:395)
>       at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$ProcessOutputFacade.err(AaptProcess.java:312)
>       at com.android.utils.GrabProcessOutput$1.run(GrabProcessOutput.java:104)

Comment: Disabling AAPT2 will not fix the issue. It will only postpone it for a bit since AAPT1 will be deprecated soon. Post the full build log and the AAPT errors you're getting so we can solve the underlying issue

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check your PNG images, corrupted maybe or not real png (jpeg for example)

You can get the list of unreal PNGs by typing following command in android terminal

```
find . -type f -name "*.png" | xargs -L 1 -I{} file  -I {} | grep -v 'image/png; charset=binary$'
```

Comment: What if there are no corrupted png files?

Comment: Check the log, here "com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.handleOutput(AaptProcess.java:443)" it's about png

Comment: This is what I get: 'xargs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 4):

i saw somewher someone add this code to build.gradle
i tried it and its solve my problem

```
lintOptions {

    checkReleaseBuilds false

    // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release 
    //builds,
    // but continue the build even when errors are found:

    abortOnError false

}

buildTypes {
    release {
        aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
        aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
        'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following statement to your gradle.properties file:

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

Also make sure to update build tools, gradle plugin and gradle version.

Comment: I am getting The option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.
Use 'android.enableAapt2=true' to remove this warning.

Comment: And the same issue facing

Comment: does 'android.enableAapt2=false'   resolve your issue? Ignore  'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated  warning its a Android studio bug.

Comment: Resolved my Issue, It was because one of my .png file
Thank you for help, appreciated

Comment: Disabling AAPT2 will not fix the issue. It will only postpone it for a bit since AAPT1 will be deprecated soon. Post the full build log and the AAPT errors you're getting so we can solve the underlying issue.

Comment: @user3555472 png file in which context you are telling please explain

Comment: My PNG image was corrupted.

Comment: This is a very bad answer, it's not only deprecated, it will not solve the problem from the source.

Answer (score 1):

i just change minifyEnabled to false .

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

At **build.gradle** file, make `minifyEnabled false`

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

And also remove this line from **gradle.properties** file

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

Comment: That's literally the opposite of what the comment above says.

Comment: when i set  android.enableAapt2=true the system finaly pointed out to my specific probleme